Does the changes of flow regimes of the renormalization group flow diagram imply always that a symmetry has been broken?
Usually we can use RG flow diagrams to understand that a phase transition has happened. Because they are intimately related to a broken symmetry, does that imply that it always implies that a symmetry has been broken?
